# Cannot select Documents from Recent in FileSelector android

Tags: android, file, upload, document

I am allowing user to select particular type of files `(pdf,docx,xlsx)` from local storage to upload it to the `php server`

**1 )** When user select file through any installed app like `FileExplorer , ESFileExplorer` , then he **can upload** the file to the server successfully

**Uri of selected file** : content://media/external/file/104310

**File path selected file** : /storage/emulated/0/Download/Bipasha-Basu-Cover-of-Noblesse-India_August_2014_08A.pdf

**2 )** When user select file through Recent from `FileSelector (Android default)`, then he **can't upload** the file to the server.

**Uri of selected file** : content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/28433

**File path selected file** : /data/user/0/com.android.providers.downloads/cache/enquiry_chat_1044781500443064.pdf

**Error Message :** java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.android.providers.downloads/cache/enquiry_chat_1044781500443064.pdf (Permission denied)

**My code:**

```
public static void openDocuments(Activity activity) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("*/*");
       String[] mimetypes = {"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "application/msword","application/pdf","application/docx","application/xlsx","application/pptx","application/pptx","application/txt"};
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose a file to send..."), MediaConstants.DOCUMENT_REQUEST);
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:readPermission="com.android.providers.READ_DATABASE"
        android:writePermission="com.android.providers.WRITE_DATABASE"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
Uri contentUri = null;

if ("image".equals(type)) {
    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
}
else if ("video".equals(type)) {
    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
}
else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
}
else if ("document".equals(type)) { //add this in your getPath method
    contentUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
}
```